# WCF WebApi Test Client, does it do anything with the body of a request?

Tags: json, wcf-web-api

I am writing a RESTful api using WCF Web Api Preview 6. I've just spent most of the day figuring out that it doesn't like "prettified" Json! I have a method which produces "human readable" Json, ie - it spreads the text over multiple lines to make it look nice ...

```
{
  "fieldname": "value"
}
```

I eventually track down a strange problem I was having to the fact that I had pretty Json. If I changed it to this ...

```
{ "fieldname": "value" }
```

... it worked perfectly.

**BUT**, if I pasted the first example into the test client then it worked perfectly. Since it worked I dismissed that as being the cause very early on in my investigations. But, I came back around to it after having eliminated every other possibility.

The error I was getting was a bit misleading ...

> System.InvalidOperationException: The service operation 'Post'
>   expected a value assignable to type 'MyType' for input parameter
>   'resource' but received a value of type 'HttpRequestMessage`1'.

So, my question is. Does the test client do something to the body of the request to make it work with the built-in serializer?

Comment: please provide the api method signature you are calling and your full poco code of MyType (with serialization code, if used).

Comment: This was a question regarding the deserialisation and why it works for badly formed json when using the test client, but since the wcf web api is no more it's not really a relevant question anymore. I'll close it. Apologies for any confusion caused.